# SharePoint Designer 2013 Interface not saving or updating to reflect actual file state

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2013, properties, bug, save

I am noticing a few issues with SharePoint Designer 2013 and I am wondering if I am doing something wrong and if there are any fixes.

I am working on Publishing Site Page Layout.  I try to save a file and it tells me that there is another more recent file on the server.  So I close the file (lose changes), refresh with the green 'refresh icon' at the top and then open the file again.  The file has a green check mark next to it even though it says 'checked in' under the 'File Information'... I check it out.

I make the same changes to the file.  I click save.  Again I get the popup telling me that there is a more recent version on the server.  I decide to overwrite now and click Yes.  The popup does not go away.  I click yes again... since this doesnt seem to do anything I click Cancel.  Now it starts communicating with the server and gives me the ability to save the file with a different name.  I enter a new name and now it says that if I save it the new copy will not be a Page Layout... (wtf?)

I cancel, and close the file again.  I open the file... and it appears the changes I made when I clicked saved above have actually been saved.

What the flying flashgordon is going on?

I am also seeing icons indicating customization of masterpage files that have been reverted to the site definition, and Page Layout title field that does not update when I change it via the Properties in SPD or through the 'MasterPages and page layouts' page in the web application.

Are these bugs with SPD or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I checked in a major version of Page Layout A, then opened it up and made some changes.  I saved, no problem.  More changes, tried to save, and now I get the 'A more recent version of the file has been saved to the server yesterday'.  I decide to try to start over.  I copied and pasted the file that was giving me the issue and gave it a new name.  Opened it up (the first change from above was saved fine(?), made one change, ->save and wouldn't you know it, the file that I just created has a more recent version on the server that was created yesterday... and clicking yes does nothing.  Help???

Answer (score 2):

According to your post, my understanding is that you could not save change to a file in 
SharePoint Designer.

You can go to the masterpage gallery in SharePoint Designer, right-click on the file and select "Reset to site definition", then check whether it works.

For more information: [Unable to update page layout](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60689/unable-to-update-page-layout)

Could you edit the site and save changes with Sharepoint Designer from another client computer?

If so you might want to try to run a repair of SharePoint Designer.  To do this (in Windows 7) from the Start menu go to Control Panel > Programs and Features > Locate the program for SharePoint Designer and select Change, this should start the Install wizard and you should be able to select the Repair Option.